# Why $\limsup$ in the strong law of large numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an $L^1$ sequence of random variables that are independently and identically distributed with mean $\mu$. Let
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mathbb{E}[X_i]).$$ The strong law of large numbers gives a pointwise statement about this sequence. Namely, the set of all $\omega$ such that $S_n$ converges strongly to $\mu$, i.e.
$$\|\frac1nS_n(\omega)\| \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as } n \rightarrow \infty$$
has probability 1.

I understand this interpretation and how it differs from the weak law. However, in Klenke's book he gives the strong law of large numbers as the property
$$\mathbf{P}\Big[\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \big|\frac{1}{n}S_n\big| = 0 \Big] = 1.$$
How is this definition equivalent to the idea I outlined above? Intuitively, what is the role of $\limsup$ here and why not write it as just $\lim$?

Comment: Your interpretation of the strong law of large numbers is wrong and doesn't even make any sense. Klenke's statement of the strong law of large numbers is fine, though it is more idiomatic to write $P(\lim S_n/n =0)=1$

Comment: Isn't $E(X_i)=\mu?$ Shouldn't the expected value of $S_n$ be zero?

Comment: @Andrew I noticed a typo in my post and have corrected it now. Is my interpretation still incorrect?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes that was a typo, I have corrected my post. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Any sequence whose absolute values have limsup equals 0 converges to 0

Comment: Actually I didn’t even realize you wrote $S_n$ instead of $S_n/n$. The much bigger issue with your interpretation of SLLN is you write the set of $\omega$ such that $S_n/n$ converges strongly to $0$ has probability $1$. This statement is completely meaningless

Comment: 1) events are sets, $\omega$ is not an event, but this is just a nitpick. 2) presumably $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L^1$ norm. If so, what is $\omega$ doing here, and if not, then why are you writing converges strongly? 3) if you are allowing your $X_i$ to be Banach space valued, then fine, but you should make it clear and not call it a random variable otherwise you will confuse people. This is also quite confusing since you are referencing Klenke who is not talking about Banach valued random elements.

Comment: @Andrew Oh yes you are right about $\omega$ not being an event. I am still getting used to the probability terminology. What I meant was to take $\omega$ to be any point in the domain of $S_n$ and for the random variables to be real-valued so that $\| \cdot \|$ could just as well be the absolute value $| \cdot |$. I am guess this is why Klenke uses $| \cdot|$ instead of $\| \cdot \|$? Is this interpretation now correct?

Comment: @Enredanrestos But why not just write $\lim$ instead? Is there some reason to choose $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$ here?

Comment: @CBBAM the general reason for why one writes $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$ is that the former always exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$, while the latter does not (but if $\lim$ exists in $[-\infty,\infty]$ then $\limsup=\liminf=\lim$). And another thing to keep in mind is that $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=0$ (i.e the limit exists and equals $0$) iff $\limsup\limits_{x\to a}|f(x)|=0$ (existence is automatic, we just need to check it is $0$). Basically, $\limsup$ always exists so it’s easier/more convenient to make statements with it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh I see, so by adding $\limsup$ we have a more general statement. Thank you.

Comment: usually statements with $\limsup$ are more general, but here it is not (see my second sentence)… but $\limsup$ is always more convenient to state things with.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, your second sentence makes it clear why they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any sequence has the $\limsup$ of its absolute values equal to 0, then the sequence converges to 0. Simply the $\liminf$ is sandwiched between 0 and the $\limsup$.

I have not read the book you mention. Unless the author explicitly explains, I can only speculate: maybe the $\limsup$ proof of the fact is more direct(?). It is a "weaker" result at face value. However, from the assertion stated above, it is in fact completely equivalent to the "$\lim$" statement.

Comment: Thank you. Based on some of the comments and I am starting to doubt if my understanding of the strong law of large numbers is correct. Is the interpretation I have in my post correct?

Comment: I think the problem/question is well written and your interpretation is correct. SLLN is an statement about a set having probability 1, namely, the set $\{\omega \in \Omega | \frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}\to0\}$. 
Not sure why put E(X_i) in the first equation instead of mu. Or why using  the double bar (||.|| ) for the absolute value in the second equation. But these details are not wrong.

Comment: Great thank you for your answer and comment!